# Vue Keep-Alive - App Header won't stay alive during route changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I defined the main page of my vue app to look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <keep-alive>
      <app-header></app-header>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script>
import appHeader from '../components/Header';

export default {
  components: {
    appHeader
  }
/* etc... */
}
```

My app UI is basically starting from this component, with many different routes and sub-routes paths to show many pages, but in all pages (components) I want to show the app-header at the top of the page.

The problem is that I noticed recently, with every button clicked (that changes vue-router's route to another page), the app-header gets recreated (the created() lifecycle hook function is called)

I really don't understand why, since I added keep-alive, shouldn't it be rendered once?

Please help me figure this out, I am stuck, I literally researched the entire internet about it.

**Please note! I don't want the routes to stay alive, only the app header itself**

Thanks in advance

Comment: <keep-alive> is only valid if surround the <router-view> tag. In your example page shouldn't re-render even without <keep-alive>, because  <app-header> is persist in "base" component. So, if <app-header> is still re-creating please provide as all the code (router, etc.)

Comment: It's very strange. Can you create a minimal example that show this problem?

Comment: Hey, I am posting here 3 files:

1) App.vue - https://pastebin.com/txjaeYX9 , 2) Dashboard.vue - https://pastebin.com/xhjyfeTs , 3) router files - https://pastebin.com/YH30ixd9

Comment: Please note that at main.js of Vue I import the router and put it first parameter in an object like "new Vue({router, store, vuetify, render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app');".

"App" is an import of App.vue posted, and vuetify is a plugin you all probably know already. Please let me know if you need anything else, I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Can you guys please help me? I have no idea whats going on :(